# Leer un dato con enteros con hasta 15 o mas numeros

Tags: c++

alguno sabrá como declarar una variable que me guarde un dato introducido por el usuario el cual contenga una cantidad de números de mas o menos 15 o mas, Ejemplo: en mi país como en muchos existe el Documento de Identificación Personal el cual consta de 15 números y deseo pedir ese dato en varios programas pero al declarar la variable como int, long y long long, no lee lo que el usuario digita, si no otro numero asignado por el programa.

Comment: Este tipo de datos aunque aparentemente sea un número tu debes manejarlo como una cadena de caracteres en tu programa y no como un número como tal

Comment: disculpa y como declaro una variable de tipo string? he intentado escribiendola como tal y no me corre el programa.

Comment: En c++ es mediante un arreglo de char ej char[] dni;

Comment: ya lo intente y declarando solo la variable para introducir el dpi me lo lee perfectamente, el problema es que si ingreso otra variable también de tipo char el programa ya no responde y no me imprime los valores deseados.

Comment: Sube el avance que llevas en un bloque de código

Comment: ya lo solucione, muchísimas gracias por su apoyo.